# Why does css float add padding from child elements to the parent element?

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding

I encountered a problem/thing I can't understand when coding a website.

I have two columns, using `float: left` (and `margin: 0`, `padding: 0`)
Inside the columns are blocks

When the blocks are empty there's no problem, I can even add text to it without using `<p>` tags.
But when I add `<p>` tags in the blocks the parent columns get some padding added.

When I don't use `float:left` (so only one column) however I can use the `<p>` tags inside the blocks without padding added to the parent element.

Surely I can come up with some sort of fix, but I also want to understand why this happens and if anyone knows how, how to revert this strange behaviour.

I have a live problem demo working [here](http://payitforwardarnhem.nl/floattest/).

```
<style>
#html, body{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       height: 100%;
       font-size: 100%;
}

#pagewrap {
       padding: 0 20px;
       width: 960px;
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       background: #CCC;
}

.test {
       width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background: #00F;
       clear: both;
}

.column {
       width: 480px;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       float: left;
       background: #0F0;
}

.column2 {
       width: 480px;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background: #0F0;
}

.lefty {
    min-height: 100px;
       width: 470px;
       margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
       padding: 0;
       background: #999;
}

.righty {
       min-height: 130px;
       width: 470px;
       margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
       padding: 0;
       background: #999;
}

</style>

<div id="pagewrap">

    <div class="test"></div>

    <div class="column">

        <div class="lefty">
        <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="lefty">
            <p></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="column">    

        <div class="righty">
     
        </div>

        <div class="righty">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="test"></div>

<div class="column2">

        <div class="lefty">
    
        </div>

        <div class="lefty">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="test"></div>

<div class="column2">

        <div class="lefty">
        <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="lefty">
        <p></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="test"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: the p tags have a padding which causes the gap

Comment: without a decent CSS reset, all elements have a default padding & margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using floats: which are pretty hacky/have cross-browser problems (I believe), you should consider styling your elements with inline-block

Ie, for an element you want to have in a row:

```
#wrap {
width:100%;
}

#main_container {
     margin:0 auto;
     width:1000px;
}

#column {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;zoom:1; //ie7 hack, does not affect other browsers
    width:200px; height:200px; background:#aaa;
}

#content {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;zoom:1;
    width:600px; height:600px; background:red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="column">list of items</div>
        <div id="content">paragraph content</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and do not forget to put a CSS reset at the **BEGINNING** of your CSS file

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;
    }
```

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. I forgot the reset. But I'm still curious why the parent-child adding of padding happens.

Comment: If you apply a p { padding:0; margin:0;} to the top of your css, does this still happen?